# Private Network in Quorum

Tags: private, blockchain, quorum

Currently I am selecting a suitable blockchain protocol for a particular application. Thereby, I noticed the Quorum blockchain protocol. On this, I have a certain question which I found a bit confusing in the whitepaper.

Can I create a private blockchain with Quorum? The application requires that only certain parties can read and write transactions. All other parties must not have access to the blockchain.

If this is not possible, can you create a general Smart Contract that enables this?

Answer (score -1):

**Quorum would meet your requirements:**

> Can I create a private blockchain with Quorum?

Yes! As soon as you set up your own network, you have a private blockchain. Here are a few [examples](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-examples) how to set up a network with Quorum

> The application requires that only certain parties can read and write
>   transactions. All other parties must not have access to the
>   blockchain.

Quorum has multiple levels of permissioning:

- Node/Network Level (https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/wiki/Security#network-permissioning)
- Transaction Level (https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/wiki/Transaction-Processing#processing-transactions)
- Smart contract level (https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.7/structure-of-a-contract.html#function-modifiers)